# composer not downloading latest composer.json from github?

Tags: composer-php, phpseclib

Here's my projects composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "0.3.x"
    }
}
```

Here's phpseclib's composer.json:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/composer.json

Note how that file has in it this line:

```
        "System": "phpseclib/"
```

When I do `cat vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/composer.json` I don't see that line. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You have told Composer to download the latest tagged version of "phpseclib/phpseclib" that matches "0.3.x".

First - there is no version tagged since they added `"System": "phpseclib/"` so Composer isn't downloading it. You should set the required version to be `dev-master` if you want to get the absolutely latest version.

Second - I don't think `0.3.x` isn't a valid semver version. Did you mean `0.3.*` or the equivalent `~0.3` ?

Comment: I got them to redo the 0.3.6 tag such that it includes the `"System": "phpseclib/"` line as can be verified at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/0.3.6 (see the last commit) however it's still not working. I do `rm -rf vendor` and `rm -rf ~/.composer` and then `php composer.phar install` and the `cat` is *still* not showing that line.

Comment: Hmm, "I got them to redo the 0.3.6 tag" scares me. Composer really does not support changing tags. I've just checked and composer downloads a version with `"System": "phpseclib/"` for me. Please try doing an update with -vvv to get full debugging info to see what Composer is doing exactly.